# Detecting double click when running from terminal

Tags: key-bindings, mouse

I'm using this in my `.emacs` file to make double-clicking the left mouse button run a command:

```
(global-set-key [(double-mouse-1)] 'some-command)
```

This only works in GUI mode; it doesn't work when running Emacs in the terminal. Is there some way for me to fix this? Or to detect double click events using some other mechanism? I have tried in a few different terminals without success. Tried Emacs 24.5.1 and 23.1.1.

Note that `xterm-mouse-mode` is enabled and other mouse functionality (like single-clicking or drag and drop to highlight text) works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for `xterm-mouse-mode` (`C-h f xterm-mouse-mode RET`); you'll see that it doesn't support double clicks, or for that matter modifier keys.

On the other hand, I do see code in that same file that looks at consecutive mouse events and counts them to try to find double clicks, so I don't immediately see why they wouldn't be supported.

Answer (score 0):

I reworked some of that xtrm-mouse-mode handling sometimes around May-June 2014.  Not sure if it reached Emacs-24.5, but at least double clicks seem to work for me here in Emacs-25.